# What does “We mortals are but shadows and dust” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is from a dialogue in the film *Gladiator (2000):*

> We mortals are **but** shadows and dust. Shadows and dust, Maximus.
> <sub>Source: [*Gladiator (2000)* movie script - Screenplays for You](http://sfy.ru/?script=gladiator_ts)</sub>

Could someone please explain this sentence? Apparently, the words “dust” and “shadows” are used figuratively. Does this “but” mean “only”?

Comment: In life we are shadows. In death we become dust. Nothing more.

Comment: "pulvis et umbra sumus, fruges consumere nati" - Horace. ""as his friend laughs, Horace slyly puts his finger on his every fault; once let in, he plays about the heartstrings" - Persius

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**"but"** in your example is an old expression equivalent to **"nothing but"**. Here are some examples of use:

> - I hear of your tricks; you disown me for your mother, and say I am but your nurse. Is not this true?
> - Well, say the holy Scriptures of Truth, there is but one God.
> - in respect to which all these glories are but smoke, all these riches are but dirt, all these delights are but dreams, all these businesses are but triflings, ...

In your example, Maximus is simply stating that human life is ephemeral. The word **shadow** is used as a reference to [Plato's cave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_of_the_Cave) and the word **dust** may be a biblical reference:

- Genesis 2:7 - And the LORD God formed man [of] the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a living soul.
- Ecclesiastes 12:7 - Then shall the dust return to the earth as it was: and the spirit shall return unto God who gave it.

And [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+but%2C+is+but%2C+am+but&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20but%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20but%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cam%20but%3B%2Cc0), you can see the decline in use:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Could you say what **shadows and dust** mean here?

Comment: @Juya, it is used figuratively to express that human life is ephemeral. Updated the answer.

Comment: In addition to the biblical references above also note the phrase "Earth to earth, ashes to ashes, dust to dust" is from the funeral service of The Book of Common Prayer.

Comment: Something came to my mind: This film is about a gladiator in ancient Roman times. Is it sensible to refer to something in Bible in that time? As far as I remember the story of this film happens before the Christ.

Comment: @Juya, it is possible. Gladiator's plot starts in 180 AD.

Comment: The quotes from the Bible are from what Christians call the Old Testament, which was written hundreds of years earlier. The Jews had available written copies of that, long before the New Testament was added. Whether the Romans got it from there is another question, but remember Judea was under Roman rule at the time of Christ.

Answer (score 1):

"but" can be a conjunction expressing contrast as in: He was sad, but didn't show it.
And it can be an adverb meaning only, not more than as in There were but three people present/She is but a little girl, not a woman.

Furthermore, "but" has a lot of particular uses as shown in a larger dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

It means that

> we are nothing. We're just a bit of dust resting in the corner. We're just a shadow passing through. We won't be remembered. That's how little bit of space we take up.