# What is the meaning of " earned and acquired a unanimity of execration which has but seldom been the lot of persecuting monarchs."?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Thus Isdigerd alternately oppressed the two religious professions, to one or other of which belonged the great mass of his subjects; and, having in this way given both parties reason to hate him,
> **earned and acquired a unanimity of execration which has but seldom been
> the lot of persecuting monarchs.**

Source: [The Seven Great Monarchies Of The Ancient Eastern World, Vol 7](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm)

Comment: A rare case of a monarch being hated by everybody (by his own actions).

Comment: Which *exact* parts of the highlighted text don't you understand? If the answer is simply "all of it", I suggest you forget about using such highly stylised text as a way to learn English. Bear in mind this text is *deliberately* written in a convoluted style with obscure vocabulary ***in order to challenge native Anglophone readers and make them pay attention***. It's certainly not intended as a "teaching aid" for non-Anglophones.

Comment: @FumbleFingers   " which has but seldom been"  confused me

Comment: "but seldom" means roughly the same as "rarely" or "infrequently" or "not often".

Comment: Ah right - *now* we're getting somewhere! Does it help you if I tell you that *which has but seldom been the lot of X* is a roundabout / stylised way of saying *which has not often happened to X*   (where ***but seldom*** is just a fancy / dated / formal alternative to ***only rarely***)?

Comment: I assume it's easy for anyone to look up the fact that ***seldom = rarely, infrequently***, because that's the ***only*** thing it means. But it's not *quite* so easy with the cited use of ***but***, because that has ***a lot*** of different meanings, and this particular one *(**but = only, merely, just**)* is *relatively* uncommon. So a related (dup?) question here on ELL is [What does *“We mortals are **but** shadows and dust” mean?*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18374/what-does-we-mortals-are-but-shadows-and-dust-mean)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for your excellent answer.

Comment: Well, I guess no answers are needed then. Just comments.

Comment: @Lambie: I had already VTCed for lack of detail when I posted my first comment, and I'm not able to change that to cite [What does “We mortals are but shadows and dust” mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18374/what-does-we-mortals-are-but-shadows-and-dust-mean) now it has become apparent ***that*** is probably all that's needed here. But of course ***you*** could endorse that suggestion with ***your*** VTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q. Re-phrased as per comments; What is the meaning of  **but seldom been**

**" which has but seldom been" confused me**

---

My Answer is **"seldom been"** means **almost never existed**"

"*earned and acquired a unanimity of execration which has but seldom been the lot of persecuting monarchs"*.

could be interpreted as;

*every group showed feelings of hated, albeit justified, for Isdigerd as had **almost never existed** towards any other cruel and unjust King.*

**seldom;** adverb: **almost never:**

Ref [CED - Seldom](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/seldom?q=)

**be** verb **EXIST**: to exist or live:
formal Such terrible suffering should never be.

Ref [CED - Be](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be)